# Unable to connect to SharePoint online using infopath. Gets an error...

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I am repeatedly getting error when trying to connect to a SharePoint online site, using an InfoPath.

Though i am using infopath 2013, The error was gone but came again when turned this settings off and back on - on SharePoint admin center,

Control access from apps that don't use modern authentication

The setting applies to third party apps and Office 2010 and earlier. 
:[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Choose Allow users to browser-enable form templates and Render form templates that are browser-enabled by users from SharePoint admin center:
[image]

Comment: That is already enabled. Also related features are enabled at site collection level.